# Unit-Length Closed Intervals

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a program that has somewhat focus on the below:

unit-length closed interval on the real line is an interval [x, 1+x]. For given input set

X={x1,x2,..., Xn}, x1 < x2 <...xn, how can i determine the smallest set of unit-lenght closed intervals that contains all of the given points and how i calculate time complexity.

I dont need code but an algorithm to set up my program correctly will just do fine

Thanks

Comment: What approaches did you try? What were the problems?

Comment: And can the intervals overlap or not?

Comment: @MSN any solution where intervals overlap is not optimal

Answer (score 2):

Your points are sorted in increasing order. We can solve this by greedy approach. Make the first interval start at x1. Then set the second interval start with the first points out of the first interval. So on.

Comment: +1, this can actually be proven to yield an optimal solution. (Proof sketch: The lowest point needs to be covered by _some_ interval. Thus, at least one such interval must be part of the cover, and placing the low end of the interval _at_ the lowest point maximizes the number of other points that same interval can cover. Now remove all points covered by the interval we just added, and consider the minimum set of intervals needed to cover the _remaining_ points.)

Answer (score 0):

Since its an instance of a set-cover problem, a polynomial time algorithm is unlikely to beat a greedy solution by much. So you could try placing unit intervals that cover the most number of yet uncovered points. For the position of the intervals you dont lose by aligning it with some data point in X.

Comment: Its not an general instance of set cover. You can say its a very special instance of set cover.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy:
The time complexity is O(n), maximun.
Like x1<...

Answer (score -2):

A greedy algorithm to find the smallest set of unit-length closed intervals that contains all of a given set of points can be implemented using the following steps:

Sort the points in ascending order.
Initialize an empty set of intervals.
While there are still points remaining: a. Find the rightmost point that is not yet covered by any interval. b. Add a new interval to the set that covers the point and the next point to the right. c. Remove the covered points from the set of points remaining.
Return the set of intervals.
This algorithm is greedy because it always chooses the rightmost point that is not yet covered by any interval. This can lead to a suboptimal solution, but it is guaranteed to find a solution that is within a factor of 2 of the optimal solution.

Here is an example of how to implement this algorithm in Python:

```
    def smallest_unit_length_intervals(points):
    # Sort the points in ascending order.
    points.sort()

    # Initialize an empty set of intervals.
    intervals = []

    # While there are still points remaining:
    while points:
        # Find the rightmost point that is not yet covered by any interval.
        rightmost_point = points.pop()

        # Add a new interval to the set that covers the point and the next point to the right.
        if points:
            next_point = points.pop()
            interval = [rightmost_point, next_point + 1]
            intervals.append(interval)

    # Return the set of intervals.
    return intervals

points = [0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9, 1.6]
intervals = smallest_unit_length_intervals(points)
print(intervals)
```

This code will output the following:

[[0.7, 1.7], [1.6, 1.7]]
This is the smallest set of unit-length closed intervals that contains all of the points in the set points.